# How to determine valid menu options given a list of valid combinations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filtering

I have a menu from which a user will have to pick a single option off of every row.

Mockup:

[image: Menu mockup]

This menu is represented in data like this:

```js
menu = [
  [41, 36, 573, 572],
  [47, 96, 79],
  [480, 479]
]
```

The number of rows is variable, as is the number of options in each. The numbers that represent each option are always unique.

The issue is that not every combination is valid. I have a list of the "allowed" combinations available like this:

```js
variants = [
  [36, 47, 480],
  [41, 96, 480],
  [41, 79, 479],
  [41, 47, 479],
  [572, 47, 479],
  [573, 47, 479],
]
```

I have access to an array that grows with each choice selected:

```js
options = []
options = [41]
options = [41, 47]
options = [41, 47, 479]
```

Because not every combination is valid, menu options that would result in invalid combinations must be disabled, so given the `options` array, I need an algorithm that generates a data structure like this:

```js
menu_toggles = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, false, true],
  [false, true]
]
```

This structure can then be used to enable or disable the actual menu options as in the mockup.

To simplify things:

- The user has to pick one option from the first row, and then the one below, and so on.
- If an option in an earlier row is selected, the options selected after that one are removed.
- Options that cannot result in a valid combination need to be disabled, ie. the corresponding place in `menu_toggles` must be `false`.

### Examples

Using the `menu` and `variants` above.

#### No options selected

```js
options = []
```

```
menu_toggles = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [false, false, false],
  [false, false]
]
```

#### One option selected

```js
options = [36]
```

```
menu_toggles = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [false, false]
]
```

#### Two options selected

```js
options = [36, 47]
```

```
menu_toggles = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [true, false]
]
```

#### Two options selected (other)

```js
options = [41, 47]
```

```
menu_toggles = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [false, true]
]
```

### Current approach (as of this writing)

My current solution looks like this:

```js
const available_variants = variants
  .filter(v => {
    if (!v) return false;
    if (!options.every((o, i) => o === v[i])) return false;
    return true;
  });

const menu_toggles = [
  ...menu
    .slice(0, options.length)
      .map(l => l
        .map(() => true)),

  ...menu
    .slice(options.length)
      .map((z, i) => z
        .map((value, j) => available_variants
          .some(v => v[i + options.length] === value)))
];
```

In this one, I first make a list of combinations that make sense for the "next" row to select, but obviously this only disables menu options from that row down.

Comment: Does it matter what order they click the buttons in? For example, if `41, 66, 100` is a valid combination, then after the user clicks 41, should 100 and 66 both be clickable, or should 100 be disabled?

Comment: btw, what would be the result of all option starting from empty array to the filled array?

Comment: @TKoL I mention near the end of the post that the user can only select one row at a time, starting from the top, and this is to obviate that question.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: you have `options` which is filling with selected choices. what `menu_toggles` would you like to get for all options starting with empty `options` and the filled by one item, what `menu_toggles` would you like to get and with two items in `options` what `menu_toggles` do you expect, and so on for three items.

Comment: I understand. I'll add a section with examples, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below provides the intended behavior.

```js
const menu_toggles = menu
  .map((row, i) => {
    // This filters `variants` down to options
    // that matter specifically for this `row`
    const available_variants = variants
      .filter(variant => options
        .slice(0, i)
        .every((o, i) => o === variant[i]));
  
    return row
      .map(option => {
        // Disable options in next rows
        if (i > options.length) return false;

        // Enable option if it exists in filtered possible variants
        if (available_variants.some(v => v[i] === option)) return true;

        // Default to disabled
        return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a super basic toy example that shows you one way to approach it. In particular, I think you're interested in the `disableButtons` function.

```js
const menu = [
  [41, 36, 573, 572],
  [47, 96, 79],
  [480, 479]
];

const variants = [
  [36, 47, 480],
  [41, 96, 480],
  [41, 79, 479],
  [41, 47, 479],
  [572, 47, 479],
  [573, 47, 479],
];

const selections = [];

const buttonList = {};

function disableButtons() {
    const allowedVariants = variants.filter(arr => {
    return selections.every(x => arr.includes(x));
  });
  console.log(allowedVariants);
  const allowedValues = allowedVariants.flatMap(x => x).map(x => '' + x);
  console.log(allowedValues);
  Object.keys(buttonList).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);
    if (!allowedValues.includes(key)) {
        buttonList[key].prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
}

function render(menu) {
    menu.forEach(arr => {
    const $div = $('<div></div>');
    $('#outer-container').append($div);
    arr.forEach(value => {
        const $newButton = $(`<button>${value}</button>`);
      $div.append($newButton);
      buttonList[value] = $newButton;
      $newButton.click(function() {
        selections.push(value);
        disableButtons();
      });
    })
  })
}

render(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-container"></div>
```

Comment: btw, why is it not possible to change the first selection? i would expect after selecting the first item in the first row, i would like to have the opportunity to switch to the second button in the first row ...

Comment: Yes, that's why my current approach at the end of the question fills in `true` on every row before. The user needs to be able to go back on what they've selected.

Comment: @chitinlink this answer wasn't intended to be everything you might have wanted out of your code, this was intended to answer the specific question asked: how to disable buttons after a sequence of selections. That's why I specifically pointed you towards the `disableButtons`, which does the work there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what system to render/update your buttons you have. Here an example where it computes a whitelist based on `variants` and the current `options` and then toggles the `disabled` property of the buttons/checkboxes accordingly.

```js
let menu = [
  [41, 36, 573, 572],
  [47, 96, 79],
  [480, 479]
]

let variants = [
  [36, 47, 480],
  [41, 96, 480],
  [41, 79, 479],
  [41, 47, 479],
  [572, 47, 479],
  [573, 47, 479],
]

let options = [];

function updateDisabled() {
  // determine which ids are part of still valid combinations
  // the current options are always left clickable so that we can turn them off.
  const allowed = new Set(options);
  // so we don't have to create the check function on every iteration in the loop.
  let variant, check = v => variant.includes(v);
  
  for (variant of variants) {
    if(options.every(check)){
      for(const item of variant) allowed.add(item);
    }
  }

  // set the menu items disabled if they are no longer allowed.
  for (const item of container.querySelectorAll("input")) {
    item.disabled = !allowed.has(+item.dataset.value);
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.oninput = function(e) {
  const input = e.target;
  const item = +input.dataset.value;

  if (input.checked) {
    options.push(item);
  } else {
    options = options.filter(elm => elm !== item);
  }
  
  updateDisabled();
}

// render menu
container.innerHTML = menu.map(row => `<div>${
  row.map(item => `<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-value="${item}">
    <span>${item}</span>
  </label>`).join("\n")
}</div>`).join("\n");

updateDisabled();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a tree of possibilities and enable the menu row and disable the row after the selected level.

```js
const
    buildMenu = (menu, tree) => {
        document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = menu
            .map((a, i) => a
                .map((m, j) => `<button id="menu${i}|${j}" onclick="toggle(${i}, ${m})"${i ? ' disabled': ''}>${m}</button>`)
                .join(' ')
            )
            .join('<br>');
    },
    toggle = (index, option) => {
        const
            getButton = (i, j) => document.getElementById(`menu${i}|${j}`),
            push = options[index] !== option;
        
        options.length = index;
        if (push) options.push(option);

        document.getElementById('options').innerHTML = options.join(' ') || 'none';

        menu.forEach((m, i) => m.forEach((v, j) => {
            const temp = options.slice(0, i).reduce((o, k) => o[k] || {}, tree);
            getButton(i, j).disabled = !temp[v];
            getButton(i, j).style.fontWeight = { true: 'bold', false: '' }[options[i] === v];
        }));
    },
    menu = [[41, 36, 573, 572], [47, 96, 79], [480, 479]],
    variants = [[36, 47, 480], [41, 96, 480], [41, 79, 479], [41, 47, 479], [572, 47, 479], [573, 47, 479]],
    tree = variants.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, r);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    options = [];

buildMenu(menu, tree);
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div><br>
options: <span id="options">none</span>
```